# FQL event table does NOT return events for 2013 when you query by creator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When you make an FQL query to the event table and index using creator, it does not return any events for 2013. I tried submitting a bug report but it was marked invalid because they said they were not able to reproduce the problem using the exact query I gave them. But I think it was because I made a typo in the title of the bug report and typed "does return events for 2013" instead of "does not return events for 2013". The exact query that I gave them is displayed below. Can anyone verify this issue or let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong?

SELECT eid, start_time, creator FROM event WHERE creator = 80241467512 ORDER BY start_time DESC

You can compare to the graph API query: /80241467512?fields=events.fields(start_time)

You will notice that with the graph API results there are plenty of events for for 2013. But with the FQL results there are none. You will also notice that there are a lot of missing events from the FQL results compared to the graph API results from 2012 and earlier.

I want to use the FQL query because I will be using the 'IN' statement to query multiple page ids.

Here is the link to the bug report that I submitted: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/360659767374062

Answer (score 2):

Since Facebook is showing a unprofessional attitude towards fixing bugs, I suggest you try this workaround:

```
SELECT eid, start_time, creator FROM event
    WHERE eid IN (
        SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 80241467512
    )
    ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

Then, when iterating through all the events, filter and reject those in which the creator is not equal to 80241467512.